# How to select only data part from a list

Tags: c#

I am experimenting with lists. I have a list which is getting data from the `DataTable dt_text_global`:

```
List<DateTime> Ersch_Online = dt_text_global
                                 .AsEnumerable()
                                 .Select(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Ersch_Online"))
                                 .ToList();
```

Data in DataTable `dt_text_global` contains only date and no time.

when I use it like this e.g.

```
TextBox1.Text = Ersch_Online[1].Tostring();
```

It prints as `14.01.2014 00:00:00`. But I only want to show date not the time.

What I have to do ??

Comment: So the table only stores the date, but you only want to show the time?

Comment: Your title and question's content are different. In title you are asking to select `Date` part and in question you are asking to select `Time`, What exactly do you need ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to show only date, then use [ToShortDateString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or provide custom format string:

```
TextBox1.Text = Ersch_Online[1].ToShortDateString();
// or
TextBox1.Text = Ersch_Online[1].ToString("d");
// or
TextBox1.Text = Ersch_Online[1].ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

If you want to show only time part, then use [ToShortTimeString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or provide custom format:

```
TextBox1.Text = Ersch_Online[1].ToShortTimeString();
// or
TextBox1.Text = Ersch_Online[1].ToString("t");
// or
TextBox1.Text = Ersch_Online[1].ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: now the question has been edited and your first answer was the correct one

Comment: @Habib yep, funny question-transformer :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Thanks man!! For the help. I mistakenly wrote wrong question and then I edit it after seeing Habib post.

Answer (score 4):

Since you edited the question and now you need to show `Date` not time. You can do:

```
TextBox1.Text = Ersch_Online[1].ToShortDateString();
```

OLD Answer

> But I only want to show time not the date.

If you only want to show `Time` then use [`TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to just get the `Time` part from DateTime. Like:

```
List<TimeSpan> Ersch_Online = dt_text_global
                     .AsEnumerable()
                     .Select(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Ersch_Online").TimeOfDay) 
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: BTW it's strange that time is not shown in textbox. looks like there is no time in his `Ersch_Online` column

Comment: @Habib Sorry Man! I mistaken wrote wrong question and then I edit it after seeing your post.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Yes there is no time in {Ersch_Online} column

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the format in the ToString() method :

```
TextBox1.Text = Ersch_Online[1].ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are the different formats.